# VSCode Ruby Debugger not listed

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to set up the Ruby debugger in VisualStudio Code. I'm following guidance which has this main procedure:

1. Ensure Ruby IDE is installed (`gem install ruby-debug-ide` and `gem install debase`)
2. Install [Ruby](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wingrunr21.vscode-ruby) extension in VSCode
3. Restart VSCode
4. Go to `Add Configuration...` and select Ruby.
5. Edit `launch.json`

I am stuck at step 4 because Ruby extension doesn't show up in the list of debuggers.

Are there other steps required?

Comment: Add Configuration > More > Ruby > Install

Comment: That's step 2... done of course.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this fixed it for me eventually: https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/issues/421

You need to have a Ruby file opened in the editor and then Ruby will probably appear in the list.